# Hibernate does not find persistent set

Tags: hibernate, persistence, integer, relation

I'm reading from a database using Hibernate. I am not too familiar with it, so maybe the answer is simple:

I use the following simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CourseHelper ch = new CourseHelper();
    Course c = ch.readCourse("fkaea");
    for (Module m : c.getModules()) {
        for (Question q : m.getQuestions()) {
            for (Answer a : q.getAnswers()) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After reading the Course I can iterate through it's modules but the persistent set of questions can't be accessed. (size = '0') Although there are questions.

The hibernate config files are as follows:

First the Module mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.dao.Module" table="module" catalog="questionnair">
        <composite-id name="id" class="hibernate.dao.ModuleId">
            <key-property name="idmodule" type="int">
                <column name="idmodule" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idcourse" type="string">
               <column name="idcourse" length="12" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="course" class="hibernate.dao.Course" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="idcourse" length="12" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="omschrijving" type="string">
            <column name="omschrijving" length="45" />
        </property>
        <set name="questions" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="idcourse" />
                <column name="idmodule" length="12" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="hibernate.dao.Question" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Question mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.dao.Question" table="question" catalog="questionnair">
        <id name="idvraag" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idvraag" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="module" class="hibernate.dao.Module" fetch="select">
            <column name="idcourse" />
            <column name="idmodule" length="12" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="vraag" type="string">
            <column name="vraag" length="245" />
        </property>
        <set name="answers" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="idvraag" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="hibernate.dao.Answer" />
        </set>
        <set name="testquestionses" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="idquestion" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="hibernate.dao.Testquestions" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I suppose the answer will be simple but if anyone can help me out, I'm gratefull.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

By default hibernate wont load the collections when the list or set is used.If you want, turn off the lazy flag by adding **lazy="false"**. Then all the questions will be loaded whenever Module is loaded.

```
   <set name="questions" inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="idcourse" />
            <column name="idmodule" length="12" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="hibernate.dao.Question" />
    </set>
```

If you don't want to change you mappings and want to load a collection in this specific scenario you can use ***Hibernate.initialize(module.getQuestions());*** before you close the session.

Read more about collection mappings in hibernate [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html). Or Have a look at an example [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/03/hibernate-mapping-example.html).